# jQuery - html5sortable - Sortable plugin with Ajax

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jquery-ui-sortable

html:

```
<ul class="sortable">
                            <li id="1">Strona Główna</li>
                            <li id="4">Kategorie</li>
                            <li id="6">Spis Treści</li>
                            <li id="7">Współpraca</li>
                            <li id="8">Kontakt</li>
                        </ul>
```

I use html5sortable plugin for jquery to use sortale list.
From here: `http://farhadi.ir/projects/html5sortable/`

When I use this script:

```
$('.sortable').sortable();
        $('.sortable').bind('sortupdate', function() {
                alert(1);
        });
```

It works perfectly, I can sort list, dragging works. And when I make change alert(1) appears.

But when I change script to this:

```
$('.sortable').sortable();
        $('.sortable').bind('sortupdate', function() {
                $.ajax({
                    data: data,
                    type: 'POST',
                    url: 'update-menu',
                    dataType: 'json';
                });
        });
```

Now I can't even drag elements, it's totaly not possible. And I can't figure out what is happening here...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a syntax error here:

```
                dataType: 'json';
```

Remove the semi-colon.

Comment: You're welcome.  Did any errors appear in the javascript console?  Usually you'll see something there when you have a syntax error.